# Crossrider: Using facebook plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, cross-browser, crossrider

I started testing the Facebook plugin on a Crossrider extension but soon found some drawbacks.

I'm trying to listen for the `write_comment` event and it works fine the first time. 
Here's the code that I'm using on the `extension.js` file:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {

    // Load the Facebook plugin
    var facebookHook = appAPI.hooks.register('facebook');    

    facebookHook.addListener('write_comment', function(components) {
      alert('on write comment');
    });

});
```

The problem is that some times the event is fired and sometimes it's not. I can name a few scenarios:

- the event is fired just the first time
- sometimes more than once, I mean when clicking different comment input boxes but then doesn't work again

Should I use the plugin on this scope or on the background scope?

Is there another way to use Facebook API alongside with Crossrider Framework?

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. I managed to reproduce it and work on fixing it. [**Disclosure:** I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Okay. The same happens with the update_status event instead of being fired when we click the textarea it fires when a page loads. Please take a look. When do you think you may have those bugs fixed?

Comment: Any news on this issue? Have you been able to fix?

Comment: The issue has been assigned to the dev team to investigate but it may take a while due to other ongoing projects.

Comment: @Shlomo do have any news on this problem?

Comment: Currently, there is not update on this issue.